# Tensorflow NotFoundError: data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt; No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

I am trying to run [this](https://pythonprogramming.net/video-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/?completed=/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/) script from the YouTuber sentdex, but I get this error:

```
This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already
been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

The backend was *originally* set to 'TkAgg' by the following code:
  File "Desktop/object.py", line 11, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 71, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import pylab_setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    line for line in traceback.format_stack()


  import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')  # pylint: disable=multiple-statements
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/object.py", line 86, in <module>
    label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
  File "/home/wdjpng/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 132, in load_labelmap
    label_map_string = fid.read()
  File "/home/wdjpng/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 120, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/home/wdjpng/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 80, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/home/wdjpng/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt; No such file or directory
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Python: 2.7

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

It would help immensly if you provided the file/function you called to produce the traceback. However, in absence of that and based on the below:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt; No such file or directory
```

The *_label_map.pbtxt path is specified in two lines of the model.config file (exact line numbers depends on the model you chose).  It appears one or both the training/test file paths are incorrect.